# .htaccess htpasswd causes login prompts all over site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to protect a Wordpress install from brute force attacks on the login page (wp-login.php).  I configured the .htaccess file in the top directory of my site to look like so:

```
 # Wordpress START
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # Wordpress END

 # Protect wp-login
 <Files wp-login.php>
 AuthName "Private Access"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthUserFile /home/passwords/.htpasswd
 require valid-user
 </Files>
```

The problem I'm experiencing is, this change is causing a password prompt to appear on every single page of my site, almost like the Files tag is being ignored.  I feel like I must be missing something but I can't figure out quite what.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks very much!

---

**EDIT**:  After taking things through with Sumurai8 below, I tried password protecting wp-admin instead of wp-login.php instead.  What I found is that a Wordpress plugin "Wordfence" was causing some problems on all the pages of my site, I guess because it was trying to load an admin-ajax.php file that was in the wp-admin directories.

This is what the .htaccess file in my wp-admin directory looks like now, and it appears to be working pretty well enough I think:

```
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Protected Area"
 AuthUserFile /home/passwords/.htpasswd
 AuthGroupFile /dev/null
 Require valid-user

 # This is the whitelisting of the ajax handler
 <Files "admin-ajax.php">
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Satisfy any 
 </Files>
 <Files "*.css" >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
 </Files>
```

Thanks again sumurai8!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-password-protect-your-wordpress-admin-wp-admin-directory/) you need to protect the wp-admin folder, not the wp-login.php file. You do this by creating a `.htaccess` file in your wp-admin folder, then adding the following code to it:

```
AuthName "Private Access"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/passwords/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

For additional security, you might want to limit it to your ip only. If you do this with `require`, remember to use a `<RequireAll>` block, because otherwise it will satisfy on any `require` directive, rather than all directives contained in the block. As an additional note too: Some examples include the use of the `<Limit>` block to limit this to certain protocols. This poses a security risk on some setups due to improper handling of invalid protocols, and should therefore *not* be used.

Comment: Ah well, I guess I was trying to protect the site from brute force login attacks, I was actually following a tutorial officially on the Wordpress site that recommends protecting wp-login.php.  Anyways though, I decided to try placing a .htaccess file in wp-admin anyways since I'm running out of options, and much to my surprise it ALSO causes the problem with password prompts appearing all over my site.  Now I'm really stumped as to what's going on.

Comment: Now I am curious what happens if you comment this out completely. And what happens if it is not commented out and you delete your cache. The .htaccess file is in the wp-admin folder, right? Not in the wordpress folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ah well when I comment it out completely no password prompts appear anywhere like you'd expect.  If I uncomment and then clear my cache, the password prompts show up all over the site again.  I thought I should mention though, the pages themselves strangely enough still load normally despite the prompts, and if I cancel the prompt the pages still display and function like they normally would.  Could it be the pages, or maybe even a plugin, are all loading something from wp-admin in the background for some reason?  It's a bit confusing to say the least.

Comment: Right-click the page, and select 'inspect element'. Go to 'network' and reload the page. Look which url sends back the authorization required status code.

Comment: Oh!  That's interesting, there's a row that says authorization required, and it has a link to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wordfence_logHuman&hid=etc.  Wordfence is a plugin I've been using for security, it seems like it's doing something that's causing the prompt to appear!

Comment: I looked into the Wordfence plugin, and was able to find resources online addressing this exact issue.  Thanks very much for your thoughts walking through figuring this out, it helped a lot with getting to the final solution!